# Restsharp not giving any response

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, restsharp

I am developing an Android app in Xamarin.Android and I want to access a Web API (hosted on local IIS) using RestSharp. When I run the app it doesn't give any result nor give any error.

Here is my code

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8066/Student/?id=193");
            var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [documentation](http://restsharp.org), when creating a RestClient you should just provide the base URL.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8066");
var request = new RestRequest("/Student", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("id", "193");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
Console.WriteLine("Response: " + content);
```

Comment: my computer is attached with a router when I configured it with local Ip i.e 192.168.1.5 restsharpe give response but when i use "Localhoste" instead of Ip Restsharp dosent give any response

Comment: I think you need to put more effort in your debugging. Remove RestSharp from the mix. Do you get responses using wget? Putting it in your browser?