# I am using RestSharp, my code works on my laptop, but not in production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

Following code works on my laptop, but when i host it in production, it doesn't work, no error, no exception, no response. What could be the error. i copied restSharp dlls to bin folder. I am using C# ASP .NET. fp1 is fileupload control.

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://job.servicejd.com/post");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddHeader("secretkey", "A#S4t%");
    request.AddHeader("accesskey", "20036987");
    Encoding en = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string textLine = "";
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fp1.FileContent);
    do
    {
        textLine = textLine + reader.ReadLine();
    } while (reader.Peek() != -1);
    reader.Close();
    string requestText = string.Format("content={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textLine, en));
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", requestText, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: as in this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075979/6448640 just provide the base URL as `https://job.servicejd.com`

Comment: yaa, i did that, but it's not working, still same problem, it works in my laptop but not in production server. This is how i canged and tried.             var client = new RestClient("https://job.servicejd.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/post", Method.POST);

Comment: Did you tried using `Method.GET` ?

Comment: After chaging to Method.GET, got the following response. "Method not allowed".

Comment: I'd remove the secret keys from the post if I were you.

Comment: yup, it's a dummy key, and link too is a dummy one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you soo much for the help, found out the problem, there is a restriction on our production server, all job search portals are blocked on our server, this code worked after removing the restriction. Thanks for the help.